# ClickListener при работе со списком из курсора

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Система следующая. Загружаются данные из курсора в ресайклер. Проблема заключается в том, что почему то при нажатии, система не видит нажатый пункт.Насколько я понимаю, не передается позиция.

Код фрагмента

```
public class FavouritesFragment extends Fragment implements FavouritesAdapter.ItemClickListener {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    View view;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ArrayList<FavouriteModel> favouritesList;
    FavouritesAdapter favouritesAdapter;

    /**
     * DB
     */
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    FavouritesDbHelper favouritesDbHelper;


    public FavouritesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favourites, container, false);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        /**
         * DB
         */
        favouritesDbHelper = new FavouritesDbHelper(getActivity());
        mDb = favouritesDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = getFavouriteCursor();
        Log.d("tag", "---Number of rows--- " + cursor.getCount());

        favouritesList = new ArrayList<>();
        favouritesAdapter = new FavouritesAdapter(getActivity(), cursor, setOnItemClickCallback());
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_favourites);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(favouritesAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    /**
     * DB
     */
    private Cursor getFavouriteCursor(){
        return mDb.query(
                Contract.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
    }

    private OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback setOnItemClickCallback() {
        OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback = new OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(View view, int position) {
                Log.d("click", "Fav - onItemClicked realisation " + position);

                FavouriteModel itemClicked = favouritesList.get(position);
                Log.d("click", "Fav -  FavouriteModel itemClicked " + itemClicked.toString());

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("title", itemClicked.getTitle());
                Log.d("click", "Fav - title, itemClicked.getTitle() " + itemClicked.getTitle());

                bundle.putString("overview", itemClicked.getOverview());
                bundle.putString("release_date", itemClicked.getRelease_date());
                bundle.putString("vote_average", itemClicked.getVote_average().toString());
                bundle.putString("poster_path", itemClicked.getPoster_path());
                bundle.putString("id", itemClicked.getId().toString());

                DetailedFragment detailedFragment = new DetailedFragment();
                detailedFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.replace(R.id.main_frame_list, detailedFragment);
                transaction.commit();
            }

        };
        return onItemClickCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Log.d("click", "Fav - in Fragment some onItemClick method for what???");
    }
}
```

Код адаптера

```
public class FavouritesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavouritesAdapter.FavouritesViewHolder> {

    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
    OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback;

    Cursor mCursor;
    private Context mContext;

    public FavouritesAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor,
                             OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback) {
        this.mCursor = cursor;
        this.onItemClickCallback = onItemClickCallback;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FavouritesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_banner, parent, false);
        return new FavouritesViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FavouritesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(mCursor.moveToPosition(position)){
            String path = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.TableInfo.COLUMN_POSTER_PATH));
            Log.d("tag", "------> Poster path is " + path);
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(path)
                    .into(holder.mImageBanner);
        }

        holder.mImageBanner.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position, onItemClickCallback));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCursor.getCount();
    }

    public class FavouritesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        ImageView mImageBanner;

        public FavouritesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageBanner = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_banner_image);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }

    public void setClickListener(FavouritesAdapter.ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

Код листенера

```
public class OnItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
private int position;
private OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback;

public OnItemClickListener(int position, OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback) {
    this.position = position;
    this.onItemClickCallback = onItemClickCallback;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    onItemClickCallback.onItemClicked(view, position);
}

public interface OnItemClickCallback {
    void onItemClicked(View view, int position);
}
```

}

Код ошибки

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.borisruzanov.popularmovies, PID: 11139
              java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                  at com.borisruzanov.popularmovies.FavouritesFragment$1.onItemClicked(FavouritesFragment.java:106)
                  at com.borisruzanov.popularmovies.OnItemClickListener.onClick(OnItemClickListener.java:16)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Большое спасибо за потраченное время и изучение вопроса. В случае, если вопрос был задан не корректно, просьба сообщить мне, чтобы дальнейшие вопросы я составлял более качественно.

Comment: Ошибка говорит что элемента с индексом `0` в `favouritesList` нет , потому что он пустой .

Comment: @woesss я так и понял))) А как решить то вопрос

Comment: Ну так заполнить этот список - я не вижу где он у Вас заполняется. И мне кажется Вам нужны данные из курсора на самом деле.

Answer (score 0):

Возможны два вариант:

- Прогрузить данные из курсора в массив (например сразу после того как открыли базу) и потом уже в адаптере итерироваться по массиву

  - В момент клика "ходить" по курсору (mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) и читать данные из курсора.

Сейчас у вас как бы два источника

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Но я тогда не понимаю, как взять из массива нужную позицию. Не могли бы Вы показать на примере кода?

Comment: Если будете работать с ArrayList - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html,
то сначала складываете .add потом  .get и не забывайте про IndexOutOfBoundsException